# Error with fork() in cygwin on windows 7

Tags: cygwin, fork

I am running a simple  C program having `fork()` call with cygwin environment using gcc compiler. It compiles well but while writing `gcc Filename.c` it shows error as:

```
$ gcc A.c
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccEkivvm.o:A.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `fork'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can't we use `fork()` with cygwin on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to include the header

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

?

To the best of my knowledge, that would define fork() when using Cygwin.

Also, take a look at this question, you might be having the same problem:
[Problem compiling program using fork in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451702/problem-compiling-program-using-fork-in-cygwin?rq=1)

Comment: No, I did include unistd.h but the error is being shown .the other hello world program is running fine but the fork() call is not running .Can there be any other solution.

Comment: Just to reiterate a point made in that post: Did you install gcc seperately from Cygwin, at any point in time? If so, make sure you are using the right version of gcc